# Implementing IsDirty to properties on my Model (WPF MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model

I have an observable collection of *Suppliers* that I want to load into a gridview and then have users edit any relevant information on the supplier. My issue is I'm not sure how to implement an IsDirty field for each property on the supplier (Model) that can be changed. I have the IsDirty bits created as such

```
    #region SupplierID
    private int _SupplierID;
    public int SupplierID
    {
        get
        {
            return _SupplierID;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SupplierID != value)
            {
                _SupplierID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SupplierID");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Address
    private string _Address;
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return _Address;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Address != value)
            {
                _Address = value;
                IsDirtyAddress = true;
                OnPropertyChanged("Address");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsDirtyAddress{ get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region City
    private string _City;
    public string City
    {
        get
        {
            return _City;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_City != value)
            {
                _City = value;
                IsDirtyCity = true;
                OnPropertyChanged("City");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsDirtyCity { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region State
    private string _State;
    public string State
    {
        get
        {
            return _State;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_State != value)
            {
                _State = value;
                IsDirtyState = true;
                OnPropertyChanged("State");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsDirtyState { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Zip
    private string _Zip;
    public string Zip
    {
        get
        {
            return _Zip;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Zip != value)
            {
                _Zip = value;
                IsDirtyZip = true;
                OnPropertyChanged("Zip");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsDirtyZip { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

The problem is that when I build the list of suppliers (ViewModel), I actually end up setting the IsDirty bits to true. What is the best way to set my Address, City, State, Zip when creating the supplier without setting the IsDirty bits to true. Do I need an initialization function in my Model?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dtSupplier.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Supplier s = new Supplier()
        {
            SupplierID = Convert.ToInt32(dtSupplier.Rows[i]["SupplierID"].ToString()),
            Address = dtSupplier.Rows[i]["Address"].ToString(),
            City = dtSupplier.Rows[i]["City"].ToString(),
            State = dtSupplier.Rows[i]["State"].ToString(),
            Zip = dtSupplier.Rows[i]["Zip"].ToString()
        };

        Suppliers.Add(s);
    }
```

Maybe I'm going about the whole IsDirty approach the wrong way. I just want to know which values actually changed so my SQL update statement will only include the changed values when a user saves. Thanks!

Comment: It's better to store original values. With your current approach, suppose Zip is 100600. I can change it to 100500 and then back to 100600 and it will be dirty, while really value did not change.

Comment: This is true, which hasn't really been an issue for me, but I'm also not against storing the original values. Would you store them on the Supplier Class itself? @evk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a few things:

1. Add a flag to your ViewModel and name it `Loading`. When you are loading the ViewModel, set the `Loading` property to true. When finished loading, set it to false.
2. Pass your model to your ViewModel but do not expose it. Simply store it in your ViewModel.
3. When the property is set, check if the ViewModel is in state `Loading` and do not set `IsDirty` flags. Also, even if not in loading state, compare the values to the value in your model and see if they are the same.
4. Do not use hardcoded strings because it is easy to make a mistake. Use `nameof` (see my example below).
5. Do not let other people from outside set the `IsDirty` flag so make the setter private.
6. I am pretty sure there are libraries that do this already but I do not know of any so perhaps someone else can chime in.

Here is a hypothetical example:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Model model;

    public ViewModel(Model model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public bool Loading { get; set; }

    public bool IsDirtyName { get; private set; }
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.Loading)
            {
                this.name = value;
                return;
            }

            if (this.model.Name != value)
            {
                IsDirtyName = true;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

If you pay attention the above design, you do not even need all those `IsDirty` flags and `IsLoading` etc. You can actually just have one method in your ViewModel that you call during saving and ask it to check and return all the properties that have changed. The ViewModel will compare its own properties against the Model properties and return a dictionary. There are many ways do achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for responding this. Looks like it should work very well, I just have a few questions.

1. This example, if I'm looking at it right, has one instance of the model, but what if I have multiple suppliers. As of now I have a observable collection of Suppliers. So do I need to add a view model for each of the suppliers?

2. How do I know when to set IsLoading to true/false. Would that be in the constructor of the viewmodel?

3. If I make the IsDirty bool private can I still retrieve the value of it in a binding. The reason I made it public is so that the viewmodel could see it.

Comment: @cr_eeper **1)** For a collection you will just take my example viewmodel and pass it into an observablecollection. Nothing changes. All that changes is now its a collection that has many viewmodels. **2)** When you are populating the viewmodel set it to true. When finished set it to false. **3)** Why do you need to use IsDirty in binding? Yes I believe it will work. Try it. What do you mean so the viewmodel can see it and thats why you made it public? Its within the viewmodel.

Comment: Ahhh okay that makes sense! Thank you.

The reason I wanted to use IsDirty is to track any changes, but if I'm storing the original values in the viewmodel then I don't need to. I can just use a check when saving like you suggested

Answer (score 0):

One option is to handle the `IsDirty` logic on a different class which will store the original values of the `Supplier` object instance. You can then use that class to `GetChangedPropertyNames` or check if your object `HasChanges`.

```
class Supplier
{
    private string _Address;
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return _Address;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Address != value)
            {
                _Address = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Address");
            }
        }
    }
}

class SupplierIsDirtyTracker
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _originalPropertyValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    private Supplier _supplier;
    public void Track(Supplier supplier)
    {
        _supplier = supplier;
        _originalPropertyValues.Add(nameof(Supplier.Address), supplier.Address);
    }

    public bool HasChanges()
    {
        return !Equals(_originalPropertyValues[nameof(Supplier.Address)], _supplier.Address);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetChangedPropertyNames()
    {
        if(!Equals(_originalPropertyValues[nameof(Supplier.Address)], _supplier.Address))
        {
            yield return nameof(Supplier.Address);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use `Reflection` on your  `IsDirtyTracker` class to eliminate hardcoding the property names.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, each Supplier I create will have its own instance of SupplierIsDirtyTracker that stores the original values for its respective supplier? Also Thanks for showing me the Reflection I hadn't seen that till you and CodingYoshi pointed it out!

Comment: It's up to you if you want to have a class in which a single instance of it will track all the object instances queried from the database. Or one instance of tracker per model instance. The key idea here is to remove the responsibility of the IsDirty logic away from your model Supplier Class.